# How can I select the current index path in RxSwift?

Tags: swift, rx-swift

I need to select a specific item in my table view when using the **modelSelected()** method.

When I implemented the **itemSelected()** method I was able to select the item using ***index.row***

```
self.quickLookController.currentPreviewItemIndex = index.row
```

I don´t know now how to get the ***currentPreviewItemIndex*** of my table view. When I select it it shows a message that no data is available.

```
        _ = documentTableView.rx.modelSelected(Structured.self).subscribe(onNext: { structured in
            if structured is Document {

//            self.quickLookController.currentPreviewItemIndex = ...

            self.parent?.navigationController?.show(self.quickLookController, sender: self)
            }
            if structured is Structure {
                let structure = structured as! Structure
                let sb = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
                let documentViewCtrl = sb.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "DocumentListViewController") as! DocumentListViewController
                self.treeSource?.select(structure)
                documentViewCtrl.treeSource = self.treeSource
                documentViewCtrl.navigationItem.title = structure.name
                self.navigationController?.pushViewController(documentViewCtrl, animated: true)
            }
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

You can zip Two observable item selected & modelSelected.

```
    Observable.zip(tableView.rx.itemSelected, tableView.rx.modelSelected(Model.self)).bind {
        [weak self] indexPath, model in
        guard let self = self else { return }
        print(indexPath, model)
        self.quickLookController.currentPreviewItemIndex = indexPath.row

    }.disposed(by: disposeBag)
```